# SVN: Using SVN External properties for RTL

Tags: svn

We have a large directory structure of unchanging RTL and firmware and are developing a testbench for it with a `trunk`/`develop`/`release` structure.  We work under develop and merge back to trunk after passing a smoke test.  We `svn copy` our current work to a candidate release and have a script that merges trunk to it, runs smoke, then merges the result into trunk on a pass.

We'd rather not copy the unchanging RTL whenever we create a new candidate release.  I'm thinking that we should create a repository of unchanging code and use an external property to bring it into local workspaces.  That way the `svn copy` command would not take as long to run.  I don't care if the script takes a while to do it's update because it's automated.

Does this strategy make sense?  Will I get the effect I want?  Will the human's `svn copy` will not have to copy the external data, just the external properties?

Thanks!

Comment: Svn copy is a cheap repository-side operation anyway. Why is this taking a long time? Do you have the whole repository tree checked out or something?

Comment: Yes.  It is needed to build.